# Insert variable into video in Matlab

Tags: matlab, video-processing, matlab-cvst

I currently have two scripts. One that plots luminescence of a pixel in a video over time and another that horizontally merges two videos. The first video is an original video and the second is the same video that has been previously processed. I wanted to insert the luminescence variable over the second video in the comparison video, in the bottom right hand corner. I think I may have gotten lost somewhere though:

```
close all
clc
clear

vid1 = VideoReader('original.avi');
vid2 = VideoReader('result.avi');

videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer;

row = vid2.Height/3;
col = vid2.Width/2;

outputVideo = VideoWriter('comparison.avi');
outputVideo.FrameRate = vid1.FrameRate;
open(outputVideo);

while hasFrame(vid1) && hasFrame(vid2)
    result_vid = readFrame(vid2);

    r = result_vid(row, col, 1);
    g = result_vid(row, col, 2);
    b = result_vid(row, col, 3);

    lum = 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b;

    L = [L lum];

    text_str = L;
    position = [vid2.Width 10];


    original_vid = readFrame(vid1);
    imgt = horzcat(original_vid, result_vid);

    plot(L)
    ylim auto
    xlim([0 600]);

    % play video
    step(videoPlayer, imgt);
    RGB = insertText(imgt,position,text_str);

    % record new video
    writeVideo(outputVideo, imgt);
end

release(videoPlayer);
close(outputVideo);
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the frame contained in `imgt` to the video file. Your annotation is contained in the `RGB` variable.

```
writeVideo(outputVideo, RGB);
```

should fix it.